# Fastest way to grab certain data from a website? Currently parsing whole html into a String and sifting through

Tags: java, html, parsing, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to grab data from a website (that doesn't have an API or webservice) in the fastest way possible. I'm currently using a bufferedreader and parsing the html into a string and sifting through it for the data I want by using substrings.

I've searched stackoverflow for answers and many people say they use JSoup to do the same job, but is that the fastest way/faster than parsing data into a string?

Also, I only want to grab the same data over and over again, and the reason parsing the html into a String is so slow is because the website contains about 2000 lines. is there anyway i could isolate that part of the website I want by manipulating the URL, making the data i want into a smaller String?

inside the source code of the website, the data i need contains a `<span>` tag, while most of the data i dont need have `<div>` or `<a>` tags, & i know exactly where in the source code it is.

Solutions im considering right now:

- multithreading since i will be going through many similar pages
- own buffered reader with a skipline method, that doesn't save string and just skips over it (not sure if this is possible?)
- buffered reader that reads first String of a line and skips over it if it doesn't contain my desired tag

I imagine that using multithreading will help a ton with speed (not sure though, never done it), but im not so sure about my bufferedreader solutions. Thoughts?

If there are any alternatives to this solution, please let me know. I've been working on this forever and just can't figure it out. Thanks

Comment: _"... isolate that part of the website I want by manipulating the URL..."_

This could work ***only*** if the website was implemented to provide that specific functionality.  

In other words, if the web site provides an HTML-based API to retrieve specific information (aka a "web service"), then you might be able to do what you want. 

For an arbitrary web site, then the general answer is that this is not possible.  However, since you've provided zero details your question is considered off-topic anyway.

Comment: `is that the fastest way/faster than parsing data into a string`  -- Maybe not, but it's certainly much better than trying to parse the string by hand.

Comment: What about creating your own buffered reader, with a skipLine method that doesn't return a line and just skips it? i know exactly what line my desired content is on so maybe i can customize a buffered reader to fit my needs? do you think that would work or would it be the same? (i'm a beginner at java btw, not sure how the buffered reader works exactly lol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> people say they use JSoup to do the same job, but is that the fastest way/faster than parsing data into a string?

Jsoup offers a "convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods" [Jsoup Official Website](https://jsoup.org/).

Given that you do not provide sufficient information in your question (e.g. website you are parsing, your current code, etc.), I can only suggest that you **do both implementations** and **test-compare them for time and memory efficiency**. Multi-threading can be added to it anyway.

In general, I would recommend to **use the libraries whenever they fully address your needs**, rather than building this functionality yourself.